# How can I make sure my Mac has access to files on its own SMB server?

Tags: mac, permission, smb

I have a Mac mini that runs a Samba server through the "file sharing" option in settings.

I can create files on it and my clients can access it. However, creating files on the client end causes my Mac not to have access to those files.

There doesn't seem to be a way to change that on the client end. I tried going into properties and unchecking the "read only" option on the file but it gets checked again when I hit "apply." My clients are Android and Windows.

Comment: Samba is configured with username/passwd credentials, not by device type (i.e. Android).  Is it he same *user* attempting to access?  We’re you able to access the file prior to setting up sharing?  How are you trying to access the file via the Mac, directly or through the share?

Comment: @leem919 if you've answered your own question please post the link below and mark it answered for others in future, heres the original link you posted: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5689/permissions-for-new-files-in-shared-directory/7255

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason why companies set up shared directories - to allow or deny group read / write permissions to files.

You will want to think about how you wish to have people authenticate and whether all shares can default to everyone can write.

On the Mac - files like this typically are homed in /Users/Shared so you could move those files to a place that’s naturally open to all accounts or change the permissions on the files you chose to share from the sharing panes.

Another last bit of advice, spend a little time thinking if you can use [POSIX group / ID based permissions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253534/apple-network-share-how-do-i-restrict-access-for-user-or-staff-group) or want to layer on [Access Control Lists](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139736/how-to-automatically-apply-permissions-to-files-added-to-a-shared-folder) (abbreviated ACL) that are more granular and can do things like add a group and then deny one member of that group from files and folders.